# python create several lists from one list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have list something like `mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6]` now I need to loop over this list and create 3 new lists like this

```
 new1 = [1,4]
 new2 = [2,5]
 new3 = [3,6]
```

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: What criterion do you have for making the new lists?  Do you want to break the original into three equal parts?  Separate the original every 2 items?  What would happen if you had 8 items in `mylist`?

Comment: Is the amount of elements in the orignal list arbitrary?

Comment: main list can have unlimited items. Need to create only 3 new lists. First and 4th item need to be in the same list. Also second and 5th, 3rd and 6th like on the example. So first list will look like ` new1=[1,4,7...]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use slicing:

```
>>> mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> mylist[::3]
[1, 4]
>>> mylist[1::3]
[2, 5]
>>> mylist[2::3]
[3, 6]

>>> lis = range(1,21)
>>> new1, new2, new3 = [lis[i::3] for i in xrange(3)]
>>> new1
[1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19]
>>> new2
[2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20]
>>> new3
[3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18]
```

A good read in case you're new to slicing: [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/the-python-slice-notation)

Comment: @Goran it doesn't.  But if you want it to, you need to be more specific in your question about the behavior you're expecting.

Comment: I need 3 new lists but main list can have unlimited items. First and 4th item must be in the same list etc as on the example

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should be using `numpy`

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
>>> arr.reshape((arr.size//3, 3)).T
array([[1, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 6]])
```